# Concealing SMTP password in .NET application

Tags: c#, .net

My crash reporter sends the log via Google smtp and port 587. I don't know how but someone got the password and tried multiple times to log in to that account.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("senderemail@gmail.com", "password");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(message);
```

Is there a way to prevent this in the future? I already use SSL here and I obfuscate exe file.

Comment: You could try putting your password into a configuration file and encrypt it, which will make it _slightly_ harder for someone to get their hands on it.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to "hide" secrets in code you give to users.

Either ask user to send information under user's account OR have server with server side code that accepts whatever information you want to send and process/resend it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide secrets locally on the system using Windows Data Protection. When you first install the application - you setup the key and encrypt locally. This way the value is never stored in the code itself. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to do this is to create your own email service. Create an API that does your emailing, instead of emailing directly from your app. Call your email API with an API key. And move your username and password into your web.config file.